# GetCommonBaseClass: Readabiliy and Functionality

Tags: c#, functional-programming

I have two pieces of they which do almost the same thing. They both return the most common base class of two types. They differ in two aspect:

1. If one of the arguments is `null`, code A returns `null` and code B returns `object`.
2. If one of the arguments is an interface type, code A returns `null` and code B returns `object`.

My two questions for you:

1. Which code is more readable?
2. When it comes down to those differences, should the code:

   a. return `null`.
   b. return `object`.
   c. throw an exception?

**Code A:**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the most common type of two types.
    /// If no common type can be found, null is returned.
    /// </summary>
    static public Type GetCommonBaseClass(Type a, Type b)
    {
        if ((a == null) || (b ==null))
            return null;
        if (a.IsInterface || b.IsInterface)
            return null;
        if (a.IsAssignableFrom(b))
            return a;
        while (true)
        {
            if (b.IsAssignableFrom(a))
                return b;
            b = b.BaseType;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the most common type of one or more types.
    /// If no common type can be found, null is returned.
    /// </summary>
    static public Type GetCommonBaseClass(params Type[] types)
    {
        if ((types == null) || (types.Length == 0))
            return null;
        Type type = types[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < types.Length; i++)
            type = GetCommonBaseClass(type, types[i]);
        return type;
    }
```

**Code B:**

```
    /// <summary> Finds the most derived common base class of all the provided types, or System.Object if there is no common base class  </summary>
    public static Type CommonBaseClass(params Type[] types)
    {
        if(ReferenceEquals(types,null)) return typeof(object);
        types = types.Where(x => !ReferenceEquals(x,null)).Distinct().ToArray();
        switch (types.Length)
        {
            case 0: return typeof(object);
            case 1: return types[0].IsInterface ? typeof(object): types[0];
            default:
                IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Type>> hierarchies = types.Select(ClassHierarchy).OrderBy(x => x.Count());
                Queue<Type> smallest = new Queue<Type>(hierarchies.First().Reverse());
                hierarchies = hierarchies.Skip(1);
                do
                {
                    int maxPossible = smallest.Count;
                    hierarchies = hierarchies.Select(each => each.Take(maxPossible));
                    Type candidate = smallest.Dequeue();
                    if (hierarchies.All(each => each.Last() == candidate))
                        return candidate;
                } while (smallest.Count > 1);
                return typeof(object);
        }
    }


    ///<summary>Gets the class hierarchy of the provided type, in order of derivation, e.g. : (System.Object,CustomBaseType,CustomConcreteType,...), or the singleton of System.Object type if the provided type is an interface or null </summary>
    public static IEnumerable<Type> ClassHierarchy(this Type type)
    {
        if (type == null || type.IsInterface) type = typeof(object);
        var stack = new Stack<Type>();
        do
        {
            stack.Push(type);
            type = type.BaseType;
        } while (type != null);
        return stack;

    }
```

Comment: I definitely find the first option more readable

Comment: `object` is the base for everything, so I don't know why you *wouldn't* want to return it if there's nothing more specific.

Comment: I agree with @Bobson. In A, when `if (a.IsInterface || b.IsInterface)` is hit, you should be returning `typeof(object)` (or some other reference to the object type). As mentioned, it is the base of *every* object in the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 3):

I think that code A is quite a lot simpler, so it's also more readable. It's quite clear what `GetCommonBaseClass(Type a, Type b)` is supposed to do and `GetCommonBaseClass(params Type[] types)` is also quite straightforward.
On the other hand, `CommonBaseClass(params Type[] types)` in Code B is much more complicated, it's hard to see what's actually going on in all that code.

Also, in code A, `GetCommonBaseClass(params Type[] types)` could be simplified even more by using something like `types.Aggregate(GetCommonBaseClass)`.

Regarding the edge cases, I think that, `null` inputs should cause an `ArgumentNullException` to be thrown. (Or not, if `null` is really a valid value.) With interfaces, I think the correct behavior depends on your requirements. If you don't know, I think the safest choice is to throw an exception. It's trivial to allow interfaces later on, if that's needed. On the other hand, adding a restriction could cause a issues with older code that uses your method.

Comment: +1. The only way returning `object` given null parameter(s) makes sense is if, by design, you never return `object` for 2 "objective" parameters. After all what class does not derive from `object`? ... I hope you have good documentation!

Answer (score 1):

Which is more readable is quite a subjective question, however if you ask me I choose the first option. There's however something that bothers me more. You should never allow a potential exception to propagate in your code (this is returning null, you'll find yourself asking again if x is null, and what if you forget once???). You should handle this null value responsible or throw an ArgumentNullException(). A good approach as I see it could be returning object, since nearly everything in C# inherits from object, as you do in your second choice. You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254461/net-how-do-you-get-the-type-of-a-null-object).

Answer (score 0):

1. `A` is more readable obviously.
2. In case of interface type, the method should return null. In case of null parameter, the method should throw exception.